# Direct from manufacturer auto purchase? Smart? Dumb? Possible?

Tags: united-states, california, auto-loan, cost-cutting, contracts

Read [this](http://www.vox.com/2014/10/26/6977315/buy-car-hassle-free) article recently, and I thought of trying to purchase direct from the manufacturer. The vehicle I want has a facility here in the United States (outside my state), and I just wonder if I could get EXACTLY what I want for less by buying direct from the manufacturer and traveling there to pick it up with a friend. Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: I don't think most US manufacturers provide for the possibility of direct to customer sales (often due to the state laws protecting dealers), excepting Tesla of course.  You'd have to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

In many states the manufacturer can't sell directly to you. In those states they must use a dealer. That is the exact problem that Tesla has been having. They have been trying to get the state laws overturned but it has been a long process.

The biggest problem is the one that some stores have. People come in, play with the floor models, then go home and order them on the internet. If there were zero car dealers, how would you know you wanted to pay tens of thousands of dollars for a car you had never driven. You could realize 10 minutes after it was delivered that the blind spot is annoying.

You can't expect to travel to the factory to get your car. The final assembly isn't always in Detroit. It isn't even in the same city for all the models from one manufacturer. How would you handle the case of a Honda made in Ohio, Indiana, Alabama, or Canada?

The article implied that 30% of the cost of the car is the distribution system. That is actually low for many other products. In many cases the store pays about 50% of the final sales price for the item from the manufacturer.

Also keep in mind that in some cases the web price from the manufacturer isn't any different from the price in the store. They know they don't want to undercut their business partners.

Comment: Is there a "less fuss" option?

Comment: Yes, but 30% for one of the most expensive things the average person will ever buy.